# jsp spring tag library issue

Tags: spring, jsp, jsp-tags

I have the following mark-up in my jsp:

```
<form:select id="ddlSkillLevelCoreFrom1" path="aarKpis" multiple="false" class="notSelectable skillsFrom qar_dd war_skill5 validate[required]">
                                <option value="">Please select a Skill Level From</option>
                                <c:forEach var="skillLevel" items="${skillLevels}">
                                    <c:if test="${selectedSoftSkill.skillLevelId == skillLevel.skillLevelId}">
                                        <option selected="selected" value="${skillLevel.skillLevelId}">
                                            <c:set scope="request" var="skillLevelFromSelected">${skillLevel.skillLevelId}</c:set>
                                            <c:out value="${skillLevel.name}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:if>
                                    <c:if test="${selectedSoftSkill.skillLevelId != skillLevel.skillLevelId}">
                                        <option value="${skillLevel.skillLevelId}">
                                            <c:out value="${skillLevel.name}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach> 
                            </form:select>
                            <form:select id="ddlSkillLevelCoreTo1" path="aarKpis" multiple="false" class="notSelectable skillsTo qar_dd war_skill5 validate[required]">
                                <option value="">Please select a Skill Level To</option>
                                <c:forEach var="skillLevel" items="${skillLevels}">
                                    <c:if test="${skillLevel > skillLevelFromSelected}">                                        
                                        <option value="${skillLevel.skillLevelId}">
                                            <c:out value="${skillLevel.name}" />
                                        </option>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </form:select>
```

as you can see in the first form:select based on the previously selected value i set the same value in a variable using c:set. Then I want to use that value to filter and show all elements with bigger Ids than that value in the second form:select. For some odd reason, it shows all elements unfiltered in the second form:select. Can you detect what I am missing.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

here: `<c:if test="${skillLevel > skillLevelFromSelected}">`

`SkillLevelFromSelected` is an id, so shouldn't you take `skillLevel.skillLevelId` instead of `skillLevel` only?